# Dynamically width (and center) input based on length of input

Tags: html, css

I have absolutely positioned inputs which usually have 1 digit length as their input.

I set the input's width to 8px and everything works great. However, sometimes we can have up to 4 digits in the input. In this case, I want the input to automatically expand to fit, while retaining center alignment.

The inputs are positioned on a grid in a specific fashion and require absolute positioning.

For a simplified example, https://jsfiddle.net/joshuaohana/2var8ftL/1/

In this case I want to be able to type `1234` as an input, the box should expand with the input getting longer, and the center of the input box should remain in the same location.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="input1">
    <input placeholder="1" />
  </div>
  <div class="input2">
    <input placeholder="2" />
  </div>
</div>
```

and the css

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

.input1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
}

.input2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 25px;
}

input {
  width: 8px;
}
```

Comment: Try using width as max-content.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to make it happen is to have an element reflecting the value of an invisible input field. There is no way to adjust input width by the content without heavy trickery. That is, if you don't need full edit capabilities, like moving the cursor.

If you do, I would opt for having an invisible `<div>` element and setting its value to whatever you type in your `<input>`. Then, you'd read the width of that `<div>` and set the same width to your `<input>`. Just remember that they both need to have the same `font-family`, `font-size` and any other font-related property.

Comment: I don't necessarily need full edit capabilities like moving the cursor, it's not common that the user will enter more than 1 digit in the field... but often enough we need to account for it.

Comment: Well, on a second thought, I'd opt for option numer #2 anyway. So you'd just have your input as you do and an invisible div, which gets the `textContent` of input's value on every `input` event. Then, you can easily read that `<div>`'s width.

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to using `contenteditable` then this should be easy to accomplish

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

.input1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
}

.input2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 25px;
  transform:translateX(-50%);
}

[contenteditable] {
  border: 1px solid;
  min-width: 8px;
  max-width: calc(8px * 4);
  white-space:nowrap;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="input1">
    <div contenteditable></div>
  </div>
  <div class="input2">
    <div contenteditable></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This would work great except you see how it's not staying center-aligned as the input value grows. It's easies to see in the 2nd box, I want the center of the input box to stay, and both sides to grow away from it

Comment: @JoshuaOhana Adding  `transform:translateX(-50%);`  will give it that effect but it won't look as good for the first input